# VBA ADODB Query Return -1

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb

I am trying to connect to MS Access database with ADODB using VBA. When I run a query, I always gets -1 which should be 1. I have check the connection using *.uld test file and found OK.
Please help.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim sql As String
    Dim recdData As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sirb As String
    sirb = "12345"
    sql = "SELECT * FROM sirb_registration WHERE sirb = '" & sirb & "'"
    Set recdData = getResult(sql)
End Sub

Private Function getResult(sql As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim db_conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Set getResult = Nothing
    
    db_conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=" & CStr(DLookup("db_path", "[DB_Path]")) & ";Persist Security Info=False;"
    db_conn.Open
    rs.Open sql, db_conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    
    Set getResult = rs

    MsgBox getResult.RecordCount
    
    rs.Close
    db_conn.Close
    Set db_conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

Below is my Database sirb_registration sample image.
[image: Table sirb_registration]

Below images are Query and the Query results.
[image: Query]

[image: Query Result]

Comment: What does CStr(DLookup("db_path", "[DB_Path]") ) resolve to?

Comment: @WilsMils  I am trying to connect to MS Access Database from another MS Access database. DB_Path is hidden table which I store a path of the MS Access database which I am going to connect. CStr(DLookup("db_path", "[DB_Path]") ) retrieve a path. So that if the database's location is changed, someone can easily update the path.

Comment: @KenWhite RowCount is not what I want to know. What I am trying is that since I don't get the result and I was trying to check the return with RowCount.

Comment: I misread your question; I got distracted by the improper use of `MoveLast` and `MoveFirst`. Your SQL seems to have syntax errors. Have you tried running it directly without the code? Literal values use single quotes, not double quotes - your WHERE clause is invalid.

Comment: @KenWhite Oops.. I am sorry. I was reading other forums and some suggested to do the cusor move to Last and then First again. But that didn't work. For Double quote syntax, I tried in Immidiate windows and paste the result string in MS Access Query builder and it works. If the syntax seems wrong, please guide me with a better one.

Comment: String literals are surrounded by single quotes, not double quotes. `""12345""` is wrong, because it surrounds the literal with double quotes. The query as written in your post cannot work in the immediate window or in an Access query.

Comment: @KenWhite I just changed the code to `Dim sirb As String
    sirb = "12345"
    sql = "SELECT * FROM sirb_registration WHERE sirb = '" & sirb & "'"` and still same result which is -1.

Comment: Then that means that you have no rows that match `sirb = '12345'`. Please provide sample data and the output you expect to obtain from that data.

Comment: @KenWhite As per your request, I had added some screenshots of my database sample. Please note that sirb field (the 1st column) is ShortText type, not Number.

Comment: Noted. Also noted is that your query in the `Below images` uses single quotes properly, and the code you've posted does not.

Comment: @KenWhite I have tried with both Single and Double quotes and they both worked. Please also note that I had changed to Sigle Quotes in my code also.

Comment: A direct copy/paste from the current code in your post: `WHERE sirb = ""12345"""`. Where are the single quotes?

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry, It was in my comments. But anyhow I have pasted with my latest code in the post again.  Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft's documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordcount-property-ado?view=sql-server-ver15), even for adOpenDynamic RecordCount is sometimes always -1:

> The cursor type of the Recordset object affects whether the number of records can be determined. The RecordCount property will return -1 for a forward-only cursor; the actual count for a static or keyset cursor; and either -1 or the actual count for a dynamic cursor, depending on the data source.

Unfortunately I have not been able to find out what specifically "depending on the data source" means.

It may well be therefore that your test is here meaningless.  Have you simply tried reading from the recordset?

Comment: Thanks.. I got it. `If Not Recordset.EOF Then` works for me.

Comment: If this helped you, then please feel free to accept it.